# If $f(a)=f(b)=0$, Show that $\int_a^b xf(x)f'(x)dx=-\frac 12\int[f(x)]^2dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$\int_a^b xf(x)f'(x)dx=\frac {-1}2\int[f(x)]^2dx$

My Work:

1) Rearrangement of terms:$$\int_a^b [f(x)][xf'(x)]dx=\frac {-1}2\int_a^b[f(x)][f(x)]dx$$

2) Mean value Theorem of integration: $$f(z)\int_a^b xf'(x)dx=\frac {-f(z)}2\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

3) Cancellation of terms: $$\int_a^b xf'(x)dx=\frac {-1}2\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

4) **LHS** Integration by parts:$$u'(x)=f'(x)$$ $$v(x)=x$$ $$(f(x)x)|^b_a-\int_a^b f(x)dx=\frac {-1}2\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

5) Integration: $$f(b)b-f(a)a-[F(b)-F(a)]=\left(\frac {-1}2\right)[F(b)-F(a)]$$

6) Substitution $f(a)=f(b)=0$: $$[F(a)-F(b)]=\left(\frac 12\right)[F(a)-F(b)]$$

The end result does not make any sense, was there an error in my thought process?

Comment: Attack the problem directly, integration by parts, $v(x)=x$, $u'(x)=f(x)f'(x)$. You will finish very quickly.

Comment: How do I determine $u(x)$? Is it simply $u(x)=F(x)f(x)$? This doesn't make sense to me because of the product rule

Comment: wait I figured it out

Comment: An antiderivative of $f(x)f'(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}(f(x))^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in the "Mean Value Theorem of Integration". Even if there is a theorem that says what you want to use (I'm not aware), there is no reason for the $z$ on each side to be the same.

As for solving the problem, as André has mentioned, it is a straightforward integration by parts.