# Prove $\int_a^{b} xf(x)f'(x) dx = \frac{-1}{2}$ and $\int_a^{b}(f'(x))^2 dx \int_a^{b} x^2(fx)^2 dx > 1/4$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I know this uses an integration by parts trick, but I seem to be doing something very wrong. I'm trying to show that given f is a real, continuouously differentiable function on [a,b], f(a)=f(b)=0 and $\int_a^{b} f(x)^2 dx =1,  \int_a^{b} xf(x)f'(x) dx = \frac{-1}{2}$ and $\int_a^{b}(f'(x))^2 dx \int_a^{b} x^2(fx)^2 dx > 1/4$

For the first part, I'm trying to use integration by parts on $\int_a^{b} xf(x)f'(x) dx$.

So we let u=x, and $v=f(x)f'(x)$. Then integrating v we get $dv = \frac{1}{2} f^2(x)$. And so we have that:

$\int_a^{b} xf(x)f'(x) dx = x\frac{1}{2}f^2(x) |_a^{b} - \int_a^{b} \frac{1}{2}f^2 dx = b\frac{1}{2} \cdot (1) - (a)\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 - 0?$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This seems obviously wrong.  Say it is true for $f(x)$.  then let $g(x)=cf(x)$.  We still have $g(a)=0=g(b)$  but now the integral is multiplied by $c^2$.

Comment: As a concrete example, $\int_0^{\pi}x\sin(x)\cos(x)dx = -\frac {\pi}4$.

Comment: @lulu Maybe I made a typo that I'm not seeing, but there is a similar question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563223/if-fa-fb-0-show-that-int-ab-xfxfxdx-frac-12-intfx2dx for the first part, but I still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: for the second part - see f(x) = 0

Comment: That question is radically different....the integral there  still depends on $f(x)$.

Comment: Wait, are you assuming that $\int_a^b \left( f(x) \right)^2dx =1 $?  That assumption seems to just creep in at some point.  If so, then the claim is trivial...by parts, as in your calculation.

Comment: @lulu If I understand you correctly, my part of the question assumes that the integral left behind $\int_a^{b} f^2(x) = 1$. It is stated in the body of the question

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that.  But in that case your argument by parts is complete.

Answer (score 2):

You should have
$$
\int_a^{b} xf(x)f'(x) dx = \left. x\frac{1}{2}f^2(x) \right|_a^{b} - \int_a^{b} \frac{1}{2}f^2 dx = 0 - \frac 12
$$
since $f^2(a) = f^2(b) = 0$.  I have no idea how you ended up with $b\frac{1}{2} \cdot (1) - (a)\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 - 0$.

From there, think Cauchy Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you, I see where I went wrong. I was mixing up $f^2(a)$ and $f^(b)$ with $\int_a^{b} f^2 dx$. Thank you so much! Is the Cauchy Schwarz hint for the second part? I'll mull over it. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's right. And you're welcome.

Comment: Note that $|\int fg|^2\le \int f^2\cdot \int g^2.$